# Firebase Storage share download url a security risk?

Tags: url, download, firebase-storage

I have an image saved in my Firebase Storage. I would like to display this image in multiple emails that I send. I have so far used the download URL as obtained from my Firebase console and the image displays successfully. My question is: Is this the correct way of sharing the image? Is it secure? If not, then how should I get a secure link to that image?

Here's where I got the download URL from, in the Firebase console:
[image: URL From Firebase]

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using a download URL is the appropriate way to share files outside of an application, or to users who don't need to be logged in.

I'm curious what you mean by "is it secure"? If you're sharing the object with someone, they can forward the link to someone else who can download it, but they can also just download the object and share it as well.

If you want to control access based on a particular user, you'll need to have users log in and download the objects in an application, rather than using download URLs. Granted, again, here they can take the downloaded object and share it with anyone else.

Comment: thanks. by secure i mean, they won't be able to access my storage to do anything else (e.g. upload) other than to download the image.

Comment: Correct, the download token *only* allows them to download that single file, and perform no other actions.

Comment: Great. I can now sleep at night. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mike. I want to use the non public URL option but it seems impossible to delete the public URL. Every time I upload an image it automatically creates "Download URL 1". If I revoke it, another one is put in it's place. While it may be hard to guess the URL and maybe no one will ever access it, why _must_ I have a public URL for every image? How do I turn this off? I can't see it in the console anywhere or the docs. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't offer a way to turn it off at present :(

The rationale was that it's secure (thus not posing a leak risk) and incredibly common (thus dictating it's inclusion).