# Firebase Storage security rules: After specifying "allow read: if request.auth != null" I can still access my files using the download link provided

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

My firebase storage rules are

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
  }
}
```

I am logged out of google and in a chrome browser (incognito mode) and I enter the url I got from firebase.storage (the download url link).  I can still download the file.  How do I secure the files to only allow downloads if the user has been authenticated by firebase.authentication?

My files are in the root firebase.storage location.

I have also tried

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
}
}
}
```

There is a revoke download url url in firebase.storage but it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download URL is public-access and intended for sharing the file to applications outside of Firebase.  Firebase security rules do not control access to a storage object via a download URL.  You can revoke a download URL using the Firebase Console.

See also this [answer from a Firebase team member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41814322/4815718) to a related question.  He notes:

> Using a download URL is the appropriate way to share files outside of
>   an application, or to users who don't need to be logged in.

Comment: There is a revoke download URL link but when I press it I can still access the file by the url...the url turns grey for a second or two then turns black again.

Comment: ok, so the revoke just issues another url and does revoke access using the old url.  So, as long as I don't give out the urls of the files I'm fine (kind of...you know, an admin could share the download url and then the file is public, hmmmm)